# How to use the /fill command with black wool or oak wooden planks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to know how to use the /fill command to fill black wool. I know how to use the /fill command, but I don't know how to make it fill black wool. Also how do I use the /fill command for oak wooden planks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For black wool:

```
/fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 wool 15
```

The value after the block type is its [data value](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Data_values#Data), which is 15 for back wool.

For oak planks

```
/fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 planks
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Minecraft 1.13, filling areas with black wool no longer requires the use of cryptic numbers:

```
/fill X1 Y1 X1 X2 Y2 X2 black_wool
```

Answer (score -4):

The command

```
/fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y2 Z2 wool (Number)
```

will give you a wool color.